# How to let client receive image through the tcp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, tcp

```
**server** 

const net = require("net");
const fs = require("fs");
const server = net.createServer();

server.on("connection", (client) => {
  client.setEncoding('utf8');
  
  console.log("New client connected!!!");
  
  client.write('Hello there!');
  
  client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Message from client: ', data);
    fs.readFile('./image/image.jpeg' , (err, data) =>{
      if(!err){
        console.log("Image has been sent!");
        client.write(data);
      }
      else {
        console.log('readfile error!');
      }
    });
  });
  
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000!');
});
```

### I am trying to send an image from server to client. I received "Image has been sent!" message on server side, but failed to store this image to the local host. I am wondering what caused this problem, and how to solve it. I am a beginner. I appreciate your patient teaching and time!

```
**client**
const net = require("net");
const fs = require("fs");

const conn = net.createConnection({
  host: "2.tcp.ngrok.io",
  port: 15258 
});

conn.setEncoding("utf-8");

conn.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("connect from client");
  conn.write('Hello from client!');
});

conn.on('data', (data) => {
  fs.writeFile("./image/pikaqu.jpeg", data, (error) => {
    if (!error) {
      console.log("Image has been stored!");
    } else {
      console.log("writeFile error!")
    }
  })
});
```

---

```
There is the output of client side terminal.   
 5�nⶪǻ��N���ۣ�d����B�
                       ��l^Ni5]����]`�p��̖Wi�6�QATa[t���1���u��|U�>g�׍�ѻ����=?IEw�X���C'b�;�Vy�����
    � �l���w�L�uuRo�S*�W=�Zi�K4N�JQ�N��7%�o��NyNRylE�Z���U_;�f
    Image has been stored!
    Image has been stored!
```

Comment: The `data` event is just one incoming chunk of data.  You very well may be getting multiple `data` events which your receiving code writes the 2nd data event's data over the top of the first data event's data in the file.  Instead, you need to accumulate all the data and write it all to the file in the right order.  Or stream it to the file as it arrives, appending each new one to the end of the file.

Comment: Also, using raw TCP has no protocol to mark the beginning and end of the image data.  You will need to invent a way to do that yourself.  This might be better done by having the client make an http request and having the server send an image in response to that incoming http request.  Then, the protocol is already designed for you (http).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fs.writeFile("./image/pikaqu.jpeg", data, (error) => {
```

Comment: I still have 2 questions. What is the difference between ./ and /? And I actually received that image has been stored on terminal, but the output of terminal is 5�nⶪǻ��N���ۣ�d����B�
                   ��l^Ni5]����]`�p��̖Wi�6�QATa[t���1���u��|U�>g�׍�ѻ����=?IEw�X���C'b�;�Vy�����
� �l���w�L�uuRo�S*�W=�Zi�K4N�JQ�N��7%�o��NyNRylE�Z���U_;�f
Image has been stored!
Image has been stored!
Image has been stored! What is actually happening here?

Comment: "./" is current path "/" is root path.